# Is this an attribute of an entity?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data

I defined an entity Person:

```
class Person: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var firstName: String
@NSManaged var lastName: String

}
```

Then:

```
let person = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entityName, inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!) as! Person

        person.firstName = "First name"
        person.lastName = "Last name"
```

Now I'm confused, is person an attribute like firstName and lastName? What is insertNewObjectForEntityForName?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you defined an entity named: Person ,

Person is a `subclass` of type `NSManagedObject`. This *Person* has `attributes` *firstname* & *lastname*.

if you are asking about the person (lowercase), it is an instance of your class *Person* (entity).

and `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` is the method of `NSManagedObject` Class to Insert every new managed Object record in DB. It will create a new records Row in your data table.

Answer (score 0):

A CoreData db can have many types of entities. Person is one such entity. A Person entity has attributes firstName and lastName.

Hope that clears it up.

Comment: Then what is the lower case person?

Comment: an instance of the Person class, which if you think of in traditional database terms, represents a row in a table.